# Recommended way to deploy Nuxt.js App with Express

Tags: express, gitlab-ci, nuxt.js

I'm looking into using Nuxt.js for a new Web application with an Express server / API attached in the project itself. I've created the Nuxt.js application with the npx create-nuxt-app command and selected Express as "custom server framework".

When using the development environment (`npm run dev`), it works like a charm. Now, I want to deploy the application to a server which is running pm2 using Gitlab CI. I struggle with the right way to deploy the application, as I don't think I should "upload" the sourcecode to the server and then run the neccessary commands like `npm run build` or `npm start`. So, what is actually "the right way" to deploy this application with the server?

I have SSH access to a server where I want to deploy this application & API. The server is running pm2 for managing the Node processes.

Furthermore, the sourcecode is in a repository on a Gitlab server with a Gitlab CI Runner available. The current gitlab-ci.yml does the following:

- `npm install`
- `npm run build`
- `lftp` the `dist` folder to the server

With a SPA, only the client is built and the server / API is not. We now have a, in my opinion, dirty workaround which doesn't work very well that does the following:

- `npm install`
- `npm run build`
- mirror the whole project to the server
- use a watcher in pm2 to detect changes in files
- build project again???

It looks like it doesn't work as intended and I have the feeling we are creating problems instead of solving the deployment issue the right way. We don't use Heroku, Google or any other services for hosting the application, it's just a webhosting with SSH access basically.